Numbers keep sorting alphabetically despite being integers
On my dataset in SQLite any query that sorts numbers (i.e. a GROUP BY clause) sorts alphabetically (1, 11, 12, 2) rather than numerically (1, 2, 11, 12). The data is coming back as for example 999,000,000, 998,000,000, 970,000. There are values above 1 billion buried at the bottom.
The common solution seemed making sure the column was set to integer rather than text, but the issue is persisting. I'm not using a complicated query:
SELECT
Track, Artist, SpotStreams, YouViews, TPosts
FROM
SongData
GROUP BY Track
ORDER BY SpotStreams DESC

First image is the settings for all my columns, second is the query and the result: Image of the table's schema including the datatype for every column.
Query used that resulted in the error.
Is it seeing the numbers as strings despite the different datatype?

I see commas in the stored data. It seems like you inserted strings in that column. Note that SQLite by default does not strictly check the types of data and stores any value you send. See https://sqlite.org/stricttables.html.

Is there a way for me to remove the commas? The method I tried before using REPLACE threw an error.

Ended up being able to open it in LibreOffice and literally just opening the file in there got rid of the commas! The sorting is working as intended now so it must have been interpreting the numbers as strings before with the commas intended.

You could try using the CAST function to force a conversion to integer.
As in CAST(SpotStreams AS INTEGER)

Unfortunately that just seems to grab the first three digits of the numbers so I think I just need to get the commas out of there. Probably gonna just have to throw it in a csv editor I guess?

Based on your screenshot, the numbers have commas in them, which means you have accidentally stored text values in those columns. Note that SQLite allows storing any value in any column (except in STRICT tables), read more here.
If you just want to sort the values without modifying the underlying data, you can remove the commas and cast the number to an integer in ORDER BY. This will be slow though, but is still useful if you don't want to modify any data.
-- Some sample data.
sqlite> create table numbers (number integer);
sqlite> insert into numbers values ('1,234'), ('56'), ('78'), (9);
-- These are the actual stored types. Values with commas are stored as `text`.
sqlite> select number, typeof(number) from numbers;
1,234|text
56|integer
78|integer
9|integer
-- This does not work at all since some columns are strings.
sqlite> select * from numbers order by number;
9
56
78
1,234
-- This does not work if the numbers have commas since `1,234` becomes just `1`.
sqlite> select * from numbers order by cast(number as integer);
1,234
9
56
78
-- This works, but is slower than storing actual numbers.
sqlite> select * from numbers order by cast(replace(number, ',', '') as integer);
9
56
78
1,234

To fix this, you can run an UPDATE query. Please only run this on a copy of your data since this will modify the contents of the database and you could lose data if there is a bug.
sqlite> update numbers set number = cast(replace(number, ',', '') as integer);
-- All values are numbers now, so sorting works as expected.
sqlite> select number, typeof(number) from numbers order by number;
9|integer
56|integer
78|integer
1234|integer

